# Make compatible clickboard data for excel from web App

Tags: excel

I have button on html which makes data to clipboard such as

```
1,first,11
2,second,12
3,third,13
```

Now I want to paste this on Excel.

If I paste this on excel , cell will be

```
|1,first,11|
|2,second,12|
|3,third,13|
```

then choose data-> separate
Cell will be fixd like this,

```
|1|first |11|
|2|second|12|
|3|third |13|
```

OK, that's what I want, however it is a bit troublesome doing `data`->`separate` on excel.

However between microsoft application, I can copy multiple cells to another sheets.

Is it possible to do this on web app??

Make clipboard data as compatible to excel data?

I would like not to use CSV, directly to excel.